# Filter data from Room Database and visualize in recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am new with android and room, i need to take data filtered on date from room database and visualize it in a recycler view

This is my data class:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "user_wod_table")
data class UserWod(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val description: String,
    val date:String
) : Parcelable
```

I have a calendar view in a fragment

```
private lateinit var calendarView: CalendarView

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false)

    calendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView)

    val pm = requireContext().packageManager
    val appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("it.alberto.wodapp", 0)
    val appFile = appInfo.sourceDir
    val installed: Long = File(appFile).lastModified()
    //calendarView.setMinimumDate()


    val events: MutableList<EventDay> = ArrayList()

    calendarView.setOnDayClickListener(object : OnDayClickListener {
        override fun onDayClick(eventDay: EventDay) {
            val clickedDayCalendar: Calendar = eventDay.calendar

            events.add(EventDay(clickedDayCalendar, R.drawable.ic_dumbbell))
            calendarView.setEvents(events)

            //var my_date_format: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault())
            //var my_date: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault())

            val date = "" + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)

            Toast.makeText(activity, "" + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/" + clickedDayCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_calendarFragment_to_listUserWodFragment)
        }
    })

    return view
}
```

When I click on a day, start the second fragment with recycler view

```
 @InternalCoroutinesApi
private lateinit var mUserWodViewModel: UserWodViewModel


@InternalCoroutinesApi
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_user_wod, container, false)

    val adapter = UserListAdapter()
    val recyclerView  = view.recyclerView
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

    mUserWodViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(UserWodViewModel::class.java)
    mUserWodViewModel.readAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { userWod ->
        adapter.setData(userWod)
    })
   

    view.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listUserWodFragment_to_updateUserWodFragment)
    }

    // Add menu
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    return view
}
```

Now I visualize all UserWod with no filter, but I want only UserWod in the date selected.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty list of UserWod and add elements from the original list having date as the selected one. Then use this list in the recyclerview.

```
var newlist = ArrayList<UserWod>()
originalList.forEach { item ->
   if (item.date == selectedDate)
      newlist.add(item)
}
adapter.updateList(newlist)
```

You have to create a new list everytime, so create a separate function for that.